# GWT showing 0 sitemaps links

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I currently have 3 sitemaps (as rss) on a large site.  Two of them seem to be getting indexed well, but the third (blog-rss.xml) isn't getting indexed at all:

[image: sitemap]

Any thoughts on how to diagnose what the problem is here?  Here is a short snippet of the rss feed:

[image: rss-feed]

I should add that the pages are getting indexed likely through normal links.

Looks like @closetnoc was correct in his comment below.  This sitemap is now indexed:

[image: sitemaps-indexed]

Comment: Between rss.xml and blog-rss.xml, are there content in common? Maybe blog-rss.xml content is already in rss.xml

Comment: No, they are entirely unique. Blogs is blog posts from customers usually in the form of "this is what happened today at my home's construction site" and forum is more q&a like "how do I find good subcontractors".

Comment: It has only been a few days... you really need to give Google more time. Search engines are notoriously slow because, think about it, they are indexing the entire Internet. See what the next couple of weeks gives you. Also keep in mind that Google goes in fits and starts. There are times where it will index like crazy, index at a moderately slow pace, and not index at all. It can be weeks at a time for each. Do not freak-out. This is not an indication of a problem. The fact that all three have been downloaded and that some seem to be read okay, you should be fine.

Comment: That may be and as I said, the pages have been indexed.  If you search for "Drywall nearly finished", the post comes up as a #1 or #2 hit. My only concern is that the others were almost immediate.  Within 3-6 hours, they both stated a number of indexed pages.

Comment: @closetnoc if you want to add an answer, I'll mark it.  You were absolutely correct.  They have now been indexed.

Comment: I updated the comment as an answer. I added a thought- that GWT is 2-3 days behind and that you will likely see different numbers in the morning. It looks like GWT updates about 3am EST or so. It has been a while since I looked. I am sure you are fine. Thanks for the vote (of confidence)!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has only been a few days... you really need to give Google more time.

Search engines are notoriously slow because, think about it, they are indexing the entire Internet. See what the next couple of weeks gives you. Also keep in mind that Google Webmaster Tools is 2-3 days behind normally so you may see something different in the morning. (Updates about 3am EST)

Google goes in fits and starts. There are times where it will index like crazy, index at a moderately slow pace, and not index at all. It can be weeks at a time for each. Do not freak-out. This is not an indication of a problem.

The fact that all three have been downloaded and that some seem to be read okay, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that google is slow at indexing and all that, but you could try to speed it up. Just go into webmaster tools then:

1. Select the website containing the sitemap that has/had 0 links processed.
2. Select the gear icon at the top right.
3. Select site settings.
4. Select "Limit Google's maximum crawl rate".
5. Move the slider to the right-most setting. The slider arrow should point between g and h in the word high.

Depending on how well google trusts your site and how popular it is, doing the above steps can increase the crawl rate from about 0.33 requests a second to well over 10 requests a second. Doing this might give you desired results sooner.